# How to decode something beginning with "\u" with PHP

Tags: php, unicode, decode

How to decode something beginning with "\u" with PHP

e.g.

```
\u4f60\u5df2\u7ecf\u6dfb\u52a0\u4e86\u6b64\u8bdd\u9898
```

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: Check this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140660/how-to-get-uxxxx-to-display-correctly-using-php5

Comment: Lots of string literal formats use `\u` notation, but they all have small differences from each other. There is probably one particular parser you need to match... for example if this has come from a JSON submission, you should be reading it using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP 5.4/intl:

```
$s = "\u4f60\u5df2\u7ecf\u6dfb\u52a0\u4e86\u6b64\u8bdd\u9898";
echo transliterator_transliterate("Hex-Any/Java", $s);
```

Output:

```
你已经添加了此话题
```

For versions before, you can [adapt this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480074/how-do-i-convert-unicode-codepoints-to-hexadecimal-html-entities/3552773#3552773).

Note that the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140660/how-to-get-uxxxx-to-display-correctly-using-php5) don't deal with supplementary characters (those that cannot be represented with one code unit in UTF-16).