# Convert string in php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have one string:

```
"Hello\u00c2\u00a0World"
```

I would like convert in:

```
"Hello World"
```

I try :

```
str_replace("\u00c2\u00a0"," ","Hello\u00c2\u00a0World");
```

or

```
str_replace("\\u00c2\\u00a0"," ","Hello\u00c2\u00a0World");
```

but not work!

Comment: Where does that string come from? Is it possibly a JSON encoded string? I'm smelling some serious encoding conversion problem here.

Comment: Remember that you have to assign that back to the string, i.e. `$string = str_replace(..);` - working: http://codepad.org/qcCtedUr

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524096/741747).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve!

```
str_replace(chr(194).chr(160)," ","Hello\u00c2\u00a0World");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove \u.... like patterns then you can use this for example:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\\\u....)+/',' ',$input);
```

Comment: i don't want remove but replace!

Comment: This replaces it to spaces. If you would like to unescape them, this link (mentioned by perdeu) can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180920/how-to-decode-something-beginning-with-u-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You are most of the way there.

```
$stuff = "Hello\u00c2\u00a0World";
$newstuff = str_replace("\u00c2\u00a0"," ",$stuff);
```

you need to put the return from str_replace into a variable in order to do something with it later.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$str="Hello\u00c2\u00a0World";   
echo str_replace("\u00c2\u00a0"," ",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NN1nLU), taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524096/741747)

```
function replaceUnicode($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})/", function($m){ return chr(hexdec($m[1])); }, $str);
}
echo replaceUnicode("Hello\u00c2\u00a0World");
```